# Can't figure out why a section of my css is not showing up properly

Tags: html, css

I'm staging up a site and have been using "background-color" tags in my CSS to debug where each block (section) is located. I've ran into a bit of a snag with my "#mainContent" section and can't figure out why the background-color (used for debugging) is not showing up.

Here's a link to JSFIDDLE for the entire page code: http://jsfiddle.net/JGAd6/

Here's the code associated with that section:

-- HTML --

```
<div id="mainContentWrapper">

    <div id="mainContent">

        <div id="services">

            <div class="serviceNavLink"><a href="#">Marketing Strategy</a>
                <p>Qui tonx helvetica master cleanse, odd future cupidatat raw 
                denim fugiat et intelligentsia quis semiotics quinoa. Gentrify pork belly consequat synth. Portland ethical salvia, ex sunt mustache flexitarian art party wayfarers. Tousled ennui scenester, nostrud brunch banjo raw denim pug pour-over. Nesciunt synth mlkshk keytar, skateboard fashion axe reprehenderit umami pug bespoke.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="serviceNavLink"><a href="#">Outsourced Marketing</a>
                <p>Qui tonx helvetica master cleanse, odd future cupidatat raw denim 
                fugiat et intelligentsia quis semiotics quinoa. Gentrify pork belly consequat synth. Portland ethical salvia, ex sunt mustache flexitarian art party wayfarers. Tousled ennui scenester, nostrud brunch banjo raw denim pug pour-over. Nesciunt synth mlkshk keytar, skateboard fashion axe reprehenderit umami pug bespoke.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="serviceNavLink"><a href="#">Market Research</a>
                <p>Qui tonx helvetica master cleanse, odd future cupidatat raw 
                denim fugiat et intelligentsia quis semiotics quinoa. Gentrify pork belly consequat synth. Portland ethical salvia, ex sunt mustache flexitarian art party wayfarers. Tousled ennui scenester, nostrud brunch banjo raw denim pug pour-over. Nesciunt synth mlkshk keytar, skateboard fashion axe reprehenderit umami pug bespoke.</p>          
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>  

</div>
```

-- CSS --

```
#headerWrapper, #topContentWrapper, #mainContentWrapper, #footerWrapper {
width:100%;
clear:both;
}

#headerContent, #topContent, #mainContent, #footerContent {
width:955px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

padding-right: 1em;
padding-left: 1em;
}


#mainContentWrapper {
border:1px solid #000; /* DEBUG ONLY */
background-color: #61e9a1; /* DEBUG ONLY */
}

#mainContent {
font-size: 1.2em;
background-color:ff0000; /* DEBUG ONLY */
line-height: 1.6em;

padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#services a:hover {
color: #000;
}

#services p {
width:200px;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: The background that we should be seeing is all red?

Comment: yup - just to test the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the red background not appearing you need to change your CSS to:

```
#mainContent {
font-size: 1.2em;
background-color:#ff0000; /* DEBUG ONLY */
line-height: 1.6em;
overflow:auto;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JGAd6/2/)**

I added an `overflow:auto` rule and inserted a missing `#` for your background color declaration.

Comment: yup. That answered my question (and my response to JDewzy)

Answer (score 2):

I think your missing the #?

`background-color:#ff0000; /* DEBUG ONLY */`

http://jsfiddle.net/JGAd6/1/

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that haha. But I'm still stuck with how to position those three blocks of text within the #mainContent <div>. Any idea why they're flowing outside? Do I need to define a height for that <div>, or is there a sexier solution where the div can extend all the way down to the footer...?

Comment: You can give the `<div>` a css float - `float:left`. That fixes it...but is there a reason you want to avoid that? EDIT: You would have to correctly float other things, I see that really isn't the best solution.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` also seems to work? EDIT: j08691's `overflow:auto` is probably better.